# How to make sheetname tab in vaadin spreadsheet readonly

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

In vaadin-spreadsheet tab which displays name of the sheet is editable. I want to make it readonly.  Refer the pic . Any suggestions? I have tried Spreadsheet.lockActiveSheet() API but not working

[image: spreadsheet tab which is editable now]

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is more suited as a comment, but it surpasses the maximum length...

---

In Excel protecting the current sheet does not prevent rename. However [protecting the workbook](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Protect-a-workbook-7e365a4d-3e89-4616-84ca-1931257c1517) does it, but please note **that it also prevents addition, deletion, etc**.

Since the Vaadin implementation relies on Apache POI you could try passing in the Spreadsheet constructor a [XSSFWorkbook with a locked structure](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#isStructureLocked()).

Nonetheless, looking at the [sources](https://github.com/vaadin/spreadsheet/blob/7a1c1a881bf6e2091f39556b73ea5fbcc2ad7f1b/vaadin-spreadsheet/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/spreadsheet/client/SpreadsheetWidget.java#L1658), the `setWorkbookProtected()` method seems to be setting the whole sheet as *read-only*, but I'm unable to validate this assumption since I don't have a licence for this commercial add-on (test key is already expired).

> ```
> public void setWorkbookProtected(boolean workbookProtected) {
>     sheetTabSheet.setReadOnly(workbookProtected);
> }
> ```

All in all I don't think there's a dedicated method of doing this, nor an easy workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this method as user should be able to add or delete sheets.  Is there any event handlers available which will get triggered when user changes the sheet name? I can use this event handler to prevent changing the name..

Comment: Also what how to use SpreadsheetWidget class. I didn't find any examples. I am using com.vaadin.addon.Spreadsheet to render spreadsheet